# Which is fastest? find() or standard

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering, I've started to cache DOM objects now in jQuery. For example, let's say this is my document:

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Instead of searching the DOM every time with the standard method of selecting objects in jQuery `$('.test')`, I'm caching the objects I use frequently.

For example:

```
var $test = $('.test');
```

However, now I'm doing this I was wondering what the best method for selecting a child of the cached object is.

```
$('a', $test) // the standard method, only searching the cached object
$test.find('a') // using find() on the cached object
```

Those are the two methods that came to the top of my head straight away, what's fastest? What's the best method to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first method uses the second method internally from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The API says](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) they are exactly the same.

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not sure why I've been down voted, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Probably because you could have read the documentation yourself too.